# <?php $_SESSION[]; ?> keeps getting added to index.php ? causes fatal error

Tags: magento

today when I launched my wamp-hosted website, I got this fatal error:

( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 1

Line 1 of index.php has this at the beginning, which it did not before to my knowledge:

```
<?php $_SESSION[]; ?>
```

My remotely hosted site doesn't have this..  If I remove it the fatal error goes away, but it keeps showing up after a while (Not sure when exactly, all I know is I'll be working in another window then come back and the page won't load)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  <?php $_SESSION['views']; ?>   (OR)

   <?php  $_SESSION["username"]=$username;?>
```

Comment: but should it be there at all?  what causes it to become added after I remove it?  Interestingly it hasn't happened since the few times it happened this morning.  It currently isn't there..

Comment: I can say that magento itself doesn't update the index.php in that way.  Some person or other program was the cause for sure.